# OneToOneField in Django admin not editable

Tags: django, django-admin

I've stripped my code all the way down and am left with these simple models:

**models.py**

```
class Member(models.Model):
    property = models.OneToOneField(Property, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

class Property(models.Model):
    ....
```

And this very basic admin for `Member`s:

**admin.py**

```
class PropertyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   pass
admin.site.register(Property, PropertyAdmin)

class MemberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Member, MemberAdmin)
```

While logged into the admin as a superuser, as expected on the `Member` admin page I see a dropdown to choose a `Property` model.  When there is already a `Property` model selected, the usual pencil icon to edit the selected `Property` model is faded out, so I cannot click on it.  How can I activate this icon so that I can get the usual pop-up to edit the related `Property` from this `Member` page?  I can't figure out what I am missing.

Comment: Are you aware that property is a built in python method?

Comment: @RobinAnupol I made up class names to obfuscate the actual business logic in question...

Answer (score 1):

You're not registering the `Property` model in admin.

```
@admin.site.register(Property)
class PropertyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Comment: I am... I just didn't include the code in the question.     Updating now.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Agreed with @Andrey Shipilov,

You can follow in this way also.

```
class PropertyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Property, PropertyAdmin)
```

Comment: But shouldn't. The preferred way is the decorator now. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#the-register-decorator

Comment: This was is also working for me in django 1.11 version